# Starting a developement team

Tags: project-management-style, startup

I'm going to graduate in software engineering, "I can" code in Java (Android), JavaScript (jQuery, Angularjs), HTML, CSS, i know Python and Django Framework. I've never developed big projects, but some "scholastic stuff", such as apps for time scheduling at school or an app about voting music in concerts. I studied some exams about IEEE and ISO, UML, GANTT, Use Case Diagrams, and all the time they teach us "what they do" but never "how to do them"... now I'd like to start a little team with my colleagues, but I've never managed true projects with these tools... where should I start? How could I truly learn this kind of managing from the scratch, while I've never done it in practice? Which books and/or experiences?

Sorry for my bad English, hope I let you understand what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking a Project Management Fundamentals course (there are plenty of providers of this course - accredited by PMI - you can find them online). It won't make you an expert (only the years of practice can do that, not a course) - but it will help you understand the basics.

From your question, I understand that you will be the manager in the little team you're mentioning. The methodology to be used inside the team might vary from one project to another (especially due to the *unique nature* of most projects) - but you can start with something like this and refine it on the way (especially for small / medium projects) :

**1.** Agree with the client on a set of specifications and clarify them (again, together with the client) until a point where they could be decently estimated.

**2.** Make sure you have the right people to handle the project, based on the technologies / complexity which can be deduced when the clarification is done.

**3.** Estimate - *together with your team* - the clarified tasks. Make sure to identify the possible risks which might appear during implementation - and to reserve enough time (in the estimate) for handling them as they appear. There are multiple estimation methods you can use (this is a different topic).

**4.** Based on the estimate, make a development plan. This involves being able to establish the order in which the tasks should be developed, their dependencies (tasks which cannot start until other tasks are completed, etc) and - having the estimates from the previous point - create a schedule. You can try using a GANTT diagram for this. A network diagram would be better (there are several tools allowing you to create this). Make sure that the risks identified during analysis / estimation are present in the schedule as well.

**5.** Obtain the customer buy-in on the estimates / schedule you created. Sign a contract. The nature of the contract (fixed price / time & material / etc) would depend on the nature of the project as well.

**6.** Start working according to the estimates and the schedule you created. Make sure to monitor the project closely (especially if we're talking about projects having a certain complexity) and try to foresee if there will be deviations from the estimates / schedule. If there will be deviations, figure out the cause and what you can do to stop them showing up from there on. Also, if there will be deviations from the main scope (from the initial set of specs you estimated), make sure the client understands that - estimate them separately and adjust the initial schedule as well. *And - for most projects - there will be such deviations (coming as modifications or new requests), so be prepared for that.*

**7.** Have a clear idea about when the project ends and when the maintenance / operations work starts, because that might have to be charged / handled separately.

Long story short, this would be it. I hope it helps. You can refine the methodology periodically and adjust it to your needs / working style. And keep in mind - not planning at all is actually planning to fail.
Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Eva and Lucian for you answers, it helped a lot! Thank you very much for you time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting not with the tools but rather with the goals and needs. Once they are clarified, it'll be much clearer for you which tools do you need. E.g.:

- *Launch MVP of our product and see how it goes.*
  Most likely you'll use Agile, so go on and start creating user stories.
- *Agree with the client on schedule.*
  A visualization will help, create Gantt Chart for the closest iteration and macro map for the whole project.
- *Have a transparent iteration status so that the stakeholders are informed.*
  Use burndown chart.

Hope this helps.